# AngularJS problems with ng-repeat and animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a problem with animations in a ng-repeat.

By changing the data in the collection the animation works fine for all new elements, but not for the existing elements. Even when the values has changed.

For example:

First state

1. Element "Banana"
2. Element "Apple"
3. Element "Pineapple"

Second sate

1. Element "Pear" -- no animation
2. Element "Grapefruit" -- no animation
3. Element "Orange" -- no animation
4. Element "Strawberry" -- animation works
5. Element "Kiwi" -- animation works

HTML:

```
    <li ng-repeat="elements in topicList" class="negative {{elements.class}} topic-list">
        <a ng-click="navigateTopic({{$index}})" href="" class="{{elements.icon}}">{{elements.name}}</a>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
.topic-list.ng-enter,
.topic-list.ng-leave,
.topic-list.ng-move {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms;
    -o-transition: all 300ms;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

.topic-list.ng-enter,
.topic-list.ng-move {
    margin-left: 330px !important;
}

.topic-list.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.topic-list.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.topic-list.ng-leave {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.topic-list.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    margin-left: -330px !important;
}
```

JS (changing the collection)

```
[…]
$scope.topicList = newVals;
[…]
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Can you try reproducing this in a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesen't work at all but maybe you get an idea of it: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmueller/pCHY5/8/

Comment: Your jsfiddle will work if under "Frameworks & Extensions", select Angular 1.2 and "no wrap - in <head>"